# Problema com String em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        let numero = window.prompt("Informe um número para ver o reverso: ");
        let reverso = [];
        let tamanho = numero.length;
        parseInt(numero, 10);

        for(let k = 0; k<tamanho; k++){
            reverso[k] = numero % 10;
            numero = numero / 10;
        }

        document.write(`${reverso}`);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

O programa pede para que mostre o reverso de um número, ex: 145, reverso: 541.
Estou com um problema na hora de converter o número que eu li(string) em um inteiro usando o parseInt(). Mesmo após a conversão, a variável número aparentemente continua sendo uma string e o resultado da execução não da certo.
Por favor, me digam onde estou errando.

Comment: Altera `parseInt(numero, 10);` para `numero = parseInt(numero, 10);`

Comment: Eu fiz do outro jeito que o cara mandou ali embaixo e deu certo. Porém eu fiz também do seu jeito e a saída está assim:  2,2.200000000000003,5.220000000000001. E no próprio VsCode está dizendo que a váriavel número está como String. Eu gostaria de entender por que a conversão não está funcionando.

Comment: Isso é porque lhe faltam alguns pormenores no resto do código para ficar correto. Em particular está a fazer uma divisão com virgula flutuante e deve fazer divisão inteira com `numero = Math.floor(numero / 10)`. Depois está a escrever o array diretamente na pagina que lhe vai dar virgulas, em vez disso deve usar o join com `document.write(reverso.join(''));`

Answer (score 0):

O `parseInt(numero, 10);` converte um numero numa string, e assim separado não faz nada pois o seu retorno não é usado.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```js
const numero = window.prompt("Informe um número para ver o reverso: ");
const reverso = numero.split('').reverse().join('');

document.write(reverso);
```

A ideia/lógica é:

- o `prompt` dá-te uma *String*
- com `.split('')` separas a *String* em caracteres (crias uma *Array*)
- com `.reverse()` invertes a ordem da *Array* de caracteres
- com `.join('')` voltas a colar esses caracteres dentro da *Array* numa *String* de novo...